# CSS grid auto-fill and full-width cell - empty columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a CSS layout with one or two columns (depending on page width), and a full-width `"navbar"` above them. I don't want to use a media query, if possible.

```css
* { word-wrap: break-word; }

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/* only for visualisation */
#grid > * { margin: 5px; }
.col { border: 1px dashed black; }
nav { border: 1px solid blue; }
#grid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <nav>full width nav</nav>
  <div class="col">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="col">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

Narrow screen:
[image: narrow]

Normal screen:
[image]

However, it decides to add a third or even more empty columns if the screen is too wide. I can sort of fix it by increasing the min value in minmax, but then it overflows when the page is too narrow.

[image: too wide]

This glitch does not happen if I remove the full-width cell.

How can I fix it?

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mzx6jdwv/)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code from the fiddle directly in your question. External links are discouraged because they can break or change over time and your question is no longer useful to the community. See how to create a Stack Snippet

Comment: @RaviMakwana the code is included already and you cannot resize the page to test responsivity in a snippet, that's why I used jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply increase the `minmax` width here `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))` from `300px` to `450px` but this will cause the layout to shrink into two rows to early but in full screen will fit into it so if you don't have any problem with the shrinking to early just the bellow

### Example

```css
* {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr));
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <nav>full width nav</nav>
  <div class="col">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="col">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

But if you don't like the early shrinking the only best possible way to achieve it in ride into media queries by detecting the screen size that you want your layout to shrink into two rows then there put `repeat(1, minmax(300px, 1fr));` to respect one column otherwise use `repeat(2, minmax(300px, 1fr));` for two columns.

And also by that way you can easily set the `minmax` to zero like `repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));` which will look great when the screen is too small

### Example

```css
* {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <nav>full width nav</nav>
  <div class="col">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="col">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example is just as broken as my original, if you make the page wide enough. And I'd prefer to not use media queries - this can be a widget somewhere in a larger page. Is it really not possible with just a grid? (I'm also curious what is really happening, why are the blank columns even added)

Comment: In my experience it is impossible to achieve it without media queries because you'll be setting the `minmax` which will not be equal to different sizes of page *why are the blank columns even added* are you meaning the gap between the columns?

Comment: No, try to stretch the demo to a full width, you will see empty space reserved for additional columns, but there are no elements to fill this space with. I don't understand why auto-fit is trying to make more columns than is needed. Maybe I just misunderstood how it works.

Comment: accepting the second part of your answer, the media query is the only fix that actually works for me

Answer (score 1):

this is a flexbox job:

```css
* {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap:10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

nav {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  flex-basis:300px;
  min-width:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <nav>full width nav</nav>
  <div class="col">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="col">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you *did* answer the question. I tried this now, and it works, except: we are using column-gap and row-gap to have nice uniform spacing in the grid. I can't figure out how to achieve the same thing with margins in a flexbox...

Comment: @MightyPork flexbox support the gap property (at least in the major browsers). check the update

Comment: I hope some day we can use it, but not yet https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap
Safari does not even plan it at the moment